# Form / json / js : my input doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, forms

I've made a webpage in order to get a table based on both a json and a user entry in a html form.

I have the following problem : I write my user entry in the box created by my form. When I click on my "go" button, my box becomes empty and my entry doesn't go in "Filtre_ti".

What is really weird is that if I write exactly the same entry, it goes this time in "Filtre-ti" and I get my table without problem.

To simplify : I get my table only when I write the same entry two times in a row, but I don't get it the first time.

I tried to switch positions of my script, form and table but I don't find the problem...

My script :

```js
function get_values(){

  var json = "http://****/get_json.php?callback=?";
  if(document.getElementById('Filtre_ti').value != ""){
    json = json + "&nom_TI=" + document.getElementById('Filtre_ti').value;
  }

  console.log(json);

  var titre_colindex = 0;
  $.getJSON(json ,function(data){
    newRow = document.getElementById('mon_tableau').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(-1);
    $.each(data[0], function(index, valeur){ //Pour chaque colonne
      newCell = newRow.insertCell(titre_colindex);
      newCell.innerHTML = index;
      titre_colindex+=1;
    });


    $.each(data, function(i,ti){
       var newRow;
       var newCell;

            newRow = document.getElementById('mon_tableau').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(-1);
            newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell.innerHTML = ti.TI;

        var i_colindex=1;
            $.each(ti, function(index, valeur){

              if(index != "TI"){
                newCell = newRow.insertCell(i_colindex);
                newCell.innerHTML = valeur;
                i_colindex+=1;
              }
            });

          });  //End each
        console.log("End fct");
        });    //End getJSON
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="tableau"> <!--Creation du formulaire pour l'entree utilisateur-->
          </br></br>Quel TI recherchez vous ?</br></br>
                <table border=0>
                <tr>
                        <td>Nom du TI</td>
                        <td>
                        <INPUT type="text" name="nom_TI" id="Filtre_ti">
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                        <td COLSPAN=1>
                        <button onclick="get_values()">GO</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                </table></br>
</form>
<table id="mon_tableau" border=1><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks,
Corentin.

Comment: 1. Could you please clean up your code. [opinions following] 2. Please don't capitalize HTML tags 3. Please don't use tables for layout. 4. Please don't use inline code (`onclick="get_values()"`) 5. Please rephrase your problem description, it is hard to understand what is wrong. 6. Did you tried basic debugging steps?

Comment: Did you realize that your piece of code `$.each(data, function(i,ti)...` is outside $.getJSON? So at that part of code data has no values.

Comment: Thanks for your comments
@idmean  1. I tried to clean up the code 2. I tried basic debugging steps. My json isn't the issue, I don't see any mistakes in the js part, must be in the form ? Maybe what you say in your point 4, but how can I do the onclick() without putting it in inline code ?

Comment: @alphamikevictor I checked, the $.each(data...) is in the $.getJSON

Comment: @CocoFlouq No it is not. Yo have one `$.each(data[0]...`which is inside the *$.getJSON* callback function, but the other one is outside so never will take values. Just try to use a `console.log(i);` inside to check how many times you loop.

Comment: @alphamikevictor Thanks for your help, I'm still looking but I have the correct number of loops and I don't find any mistakes in the js part... ?